# Tesseract OCR force pattern

Tags: regex, ocr, tesseract

I want to read a specific character sequence with Tesseract like this post :
[Tesseract OCR: is it possible to force a specific pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14858514/tesseract-ocr-is-it-possible-to-force-a-specific-pattern)

I have tried [bazaar](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/master/tessdata/configs/bazaar) matching pattern in Tesseract with the pattern `\d\d\d\A\A` and OCR still recognize other words which doesn't match.

I have tried to use the "tessedit_char_whitelist" parameter but I can't choose the position of the characters with that.

- I launch the command : `tesseract image.jpg result -l eng bazaar`
  And I have this message :

> Please provide at least 4 concrete characters at the beginning of the pattern

> Invalid user pattern `\A\A\d\d\d`

> Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.01 with Leptonica

- image.jpg :

[image]

- The result :

  ```
    AB123
    ABC12
    A1234
    12345
    ABCD1
  ```

So it is wrong, I just wanted to catch the sequence "AB123".

Can somebody tell me why the regular expression in my user-patterns file as no effect ? For the configuration, I have strictly followed the bazaar tutorial.

Comment: I believe this error: _Please provide at least 4 concrete characters at the beginning of the pattern_ pretty much explains itself. This is probably a limitation from whatever you are using is. Also try `\w\w\d\d\d`, `\A` is not what you want for all "characters". Try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/uQ3oQ9/1).

Comment: I tried `\w\w\d\d\d` and I have the same error : Please provide at least 4 concrete characters at the beginning of the pattern
Invalid user pattern \w\w\d\d\d.

Comment: I have added 4 concrete characters to my pattern : `TEST\w\w\d\d\d` and tested with the words `TESTAB123 TESTABC12` etc ... I have no more the error _Please provide at least 4 concrete characters at the beginning of the pattern_ but I still have _Invalid user pattern TEST\w\w\d\d\d_. I don't understand why it is invalid

Comment: Because \w\w are not recognize by tesseract. I tried to use \c\c and I have no more error message. But the result is stil wrong, is like tesseract ignore totally the regex...

Comment: Did you try `[A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9]`? Did you define it in `/path/to/eng.user-patterns`? Does */path/to/configs/bazaar* contain `user_patterns_suffix user-patterns`? Just guessing...

Comment: Yes and yes. The result is the same. There is no error, it just does nothing. I'm on windows 8 btw and I am editing the file with the unix line ending <LF> with notepad2

Comment: This feature most probably doesn't work anymore. 
https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/960

Answer (score 0):

If you add the option `--oem 0` (OCR Engine mode for Tesseract only), the `--user-patterns` option is properly enforced. See this [PR comment](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/960#issuecomment-412773829).

For a detailed example, you can read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77986836/11591342).

Answer (score -1):

Try using this pattern with quantifiers instead.

```
[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{3}
```

This should cover only 2 alphabetical characters and 3 digits.

The reason why you are matching everything before is because \w is alphanumeric.