# Can tesseract recognize sequences of letters in a image that are not necessarily real words nor bound to any human language?

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8, ocr, python-tesseract

I am trying to do that in Python with tesseract, but it seems to depend on the language to be able to deduce the characters (and that makes sense).

It is a sequence of 14 letters with any of the printable first 800 2-byte utf8 characters, but even if the recognition (OCR) is limited to latin-1 (or less) chars that would be something.

As per this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14858514/tesseract-ocr-is-it-possible-to-force-a-specific-pattern) it seems it does not need proper words, but the installer asks for a training set in a specific language.

ps. To clarify: *OCR (at least in academic setting) takes advantage of the context and of a dictionary to help discover difficult letters.*

Comment: Please, let's avoid language-tag spam. Limit the language to the one that you're currently using.

Comment: And OCR doesn't care if the text represents a "real word" or not. Your question needs clarification.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Ok, lets try only Python in this question first.  OCR (at least in academic setting) takes advantage of the context and of a dictionary to help discover difficult letters.