# Limit tesseract character to a-z and number only in my iOS app

Tags: ios, ocr, tesseract

I am using tesseract for recognizing character in one of my iOS project. It is now reading all characters including alpha numeric character. But I want to read only character a-z and numbers 0-9. I followed [Limit characters tesseract is looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363490/limit-characters-tesseract-is-looking-for), but can't figure out how can I implement this in my iOS app.

Can anyone suggest me how can I implement this in my iOS project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can specify the white list (allowed characters) using TessBaseAPI.SetVariable prior to extraction

```
 tesseract->SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz012345789");
```

Comment: the following code works for me:
tesseract->SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz012345789");

thanks a lot.... can you please edit your code, just change the syntax? thanks again..

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[tesseract setVariableValue:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz012345789" forKey:@"tessedit_char_whitelist"];
```

also you can try variable "tessedit_char_blacklist"