# How to call and limit tesseract characters into 4 Letters only in c#?

Tags: c#, tesseract

Is it possible to limit recognition of tesseract to four characters only like this **"abcdABCD"** ? I've tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15568948/limit-tesseract-character-to-a-z-and-number-only-in-my-ios-app) and created a ".cfg" file inside of my folder **TESSDATA** which is inside of my project folder.

**C:\Users\Julian Concepcion\Desktop\MyProject\MyProject\tessdata**

it is named **config.cfg**, inside the config.cfg is this "tessedit_char_whitelist abcdABCD " but I don't know how to use it inside the c#. This is how I call my tesseract

```
tess = new Tesseract("C:\\Users\\Julian Concepcion\\Desktop\\MyProject\\MyProject\\tessdata", "eng", Tesseract.OcrEngineMode.OEM_TESSERACT_CUBE_COMBINED);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do just like that link suggested:

```
tesseract->SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "abcdABCD");
```

No need to create any config file.

Comment: @nquyenq - It doesn't work. I tried this `tess.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "abcdABCD");`

Comment: @nquyenq - still, it recognize other characters

Comment: Did you call it after the `init` method?