# How to train tesseract to recognize 20 to 30 digit numbers only?

Tags: android, ocr, tesseract

I am using [tess-two](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two) Tesseract Android Tools for my project. From the research I've done I found from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363490/limit-characters-tesseract-is-looking-for?lq=1) a way to limit the types of characters, but not the range of characters.

1. The Tess-Two library I am using doesn't have a tessdata/config file, so how can I limit the possible characters tesseract recognises?
2. How can I limit Tesseract to recognise a range of digits (20 to 30)?

Comment: Do you mean numbers between 20-30 or numbers with 20-30 digits?

Comment: numbers with 20-30 digits

Answer (score 1):

If you are using your digits are in an image and the image is clear you can use the following command 
"tesseract imageName outputFileName.txt outputbase digits"
but if the image is not clear you will need to process it or you will not have the exact result.
Hope this will help you.