# Pytesseract set character whitelist

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

Does anyone know how to set the character whitelist for Pytesseract? I want it to only output A-z and 0-9. Is this possible? I have the following:

```
img = Image.open('test.jpg')
result = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config='-psm 6')
```

I'm getting other characters like / for a 1 so I would like to limit the options of possible characters.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can accomplish that with the below line. Or you can setup the config file for tesseract to do the same thing [Limit characters tesseract is looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363490/limit-characters-tesseract-is-looking-for)

```
pytesseract.image_to_string(question_img, config="-c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz -psm 6")
```

I am sure there are other ways to get it work, but this is what worked for me.

Comment: For future reference: `tessedit_char_whitelist`'s value is case sensitive so to capture `aA-zZ0-9`, you would need the full `01234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`

Comment: @Cole Does the above answer still valid? I tried `pyt.image_to_data(im_gray_res, lang='eng', config='-c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ --psm 11 --oem 3')` but still gets in results `|` for `I` and `l` for `I` ?

Comment: @SKR   You included `I` and `1` in your `tessedit_char_whitelest`, so that is expected. You might confusing a whitelist with a blacklist?

Comment: @Cole I think whitelist means to direct tesseract to only give in results the characters from the set, right? I am getting in results, pipe character `|` and small case L `l`. That's what I mentioned that I still get results from outside the set.

Comment: @SKR Oh, I get what you mean now. Sadly, I don’t know why that’s happening. I recommend opening a new question on here, someone likely knows :-)

Comment: @RexLow No, not yet, actually I tried much but there seems to be some problem with pytesseract itself in filtering out unwanted characters. I intend to comeback to this problem and if I find anything I will post here.

Comment: With tesseract 4.0.0 do not work but with tesseract 4.1.0 work OK.

Comment: Try '--psm' instead of '-psm'.

Comment: How can I give "space"  in whitelist?

Comment: how can i give `space` in blacklist?

Comment: by writing a space character and setting the whole whitelist between quotes `-c tessedit_char_whitelist='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ '`