# How to restrict the recognized characters in tesserocr?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-tesseract

When using tesserocr how do I limit the set of characters that Tesseract will recognize to just the digits?

I know from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363490/limit-characters-tesseract-is-looking-for) that if I were using c++ I could set a tessedit_char_whitelist in the config file, but I don't know the analogous approach in tesserocr within Python.

In general, the [tesserocr documentation](https://pypi.org/project/tesserocr/) gives help that works if the reader already knows the Tesseract API for c++. As I am not fluent in c++, I am hoping to avoid having to read the c++ source code in order to use tesserocr.

If anyone can give me what I actually need to write in python or a general rule for going from config settings to Python code that would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tesserocr works as the C++ API, you can set a whitelist with the function `SetVariable`.

An example:

```
from tesserocr import PyTessBaseAPI
from string import digits

with PyTessBaseAPI() as api:
    api.SetVariable('tessedit_char_whitelist', digits)
    api.SetImageFile('image.png')
    print api.GetUTF8Text()  # it will print only digits
```

---

If you want another approach that is more straightforward and independent from the C++ API, try with the [pytesseract](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/) module.

An example with pytesseract:

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
from string import digits

image = Image.open('image.png')
print pytesseract.image_to_string(
    image, config='-c tessedit_char_whitelist=' + digits)
```

Comment: This seems to completely answer the question. Thanks.

Are you aware of a source that would provide an introduction to the range of things Tesseract can do. Most of what I have found is either about installing or refers one to the C++ source code or man page.

Comment: Have you looked at [this](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/07/10/using-tesseract-ocr-python/)? It seems a good introduction to Tesseract with Python.

Comment: For some reason, we're not supposed to say  T.H.A.N.K.S on SO. If I could, however, I would definitely do so. :-)

Comment: @ceccoemi Does your advice still hold for tesseract 4.0 with oem 3?

Comment: @SKR It does not. The LSTM they are using does not allow simply removing letters for its output.