# Select part of text that was extracted using the Tesseract OCR

Tags: r, ocr, tesseract

I'm using the latest Tesseract OCR engine in R to extract text from a couple of images. It works pretty well and I'm happy with the results. The problem is that I don't want the whole text, just some part, but I don't know how to extract it.

Code is this:

```
library("tesseract") 
library("pdftools")
library("magick")

mypdfFile<-"C:/Users/.../fileName.pdf"

mypngFile<-pdf_convert(mypdfFile, format="png", pages=1, dpi=600)

myImage<-image_read("fileName_1.png")

textFile<-ocr(myImage,engine = tesseract("spa"), HOCR = FALSE) # Text is in spanish

cat(textFile)
```

Now, the end result looks like this

```
bla bla bla bla bla bla 
bla text that I want to 
extract bla bla bla bla 
bla bla bla bla bla bla
```

How can I get the **text that I want to extract** and only that?

I tried to crop the image before applying the ocr() function, but it's not feasible or very accurate to just crop that part. ocr() returns plain text.

*Full example below*

The image (originally a pdf file) is an electricity bill. I can't provide it in full due to privacy issues, but it looks like this [sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACfU9.jpg). Under **NOMBRE Y DIRECCION** (name and address), there should be two lines (one with the name and the other with the address) followed by "GALEANA CENTRO LERDO. C.P. " (the name of the city) and "35150 LERDO,DGO." (zip code and state). My code looks like this

```
myImage<-image_read("sampleImage.png")

myImage<-image_crop(myImage, new dimensions) #crop the right half and some from the top

textFile<-ocr(myImage,engine = tesseract("spa"), HOCR = FALSE) 

cat(textFile)
```

I get

```
Nombre y Domicilio
NAME REDACTED 
ADDRESS REDACTED
GALEANA CENTRO LERDO. C.P.
35150 LERDO, DGO.
Cuenta E Tarifa
30DC27B011164660 General < 25kW 02
AE A MA E
Num. de Lectura Lectura Mult. C
Medidor actual anterior
BD6687 40994 40539 1 ¿
Apoyo gubernamental
```

I just want to extract from this everything between "NAME REDACTED" and "35150 LERDO, DGO." inclusive.

Comment: We can't help without knowing if there is underlying structure to your text, depending on structure and content the answer will change. So an example others can reproduce will help.

Comment: added a full example. Hope it is enough. If not, I can provide more details or change whatever is needed.

Answer (score 1):

You could either crop the image first if you know where your text is, or you could restrict what tesseract is looking for using for example a `whitelist`, see [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363490/limit-characters-tesseract-is-looking-for)

---

**EDIT:**
After comments, we could indeed retrieve the address, here using the logic "the two lines after the line where "Address" is mentioned

```
text <- ("Nombre y Domicilio
NAME REDACTED 
ADDRESS REDACTED
GALEANA CENTRO LERDO. C.P.
35150 LERDO, DGO.
Cuenta E Tarifa
30DC27B011164660 General < 25kW 02
AE A MA E
Num. de Lectura Lectura Mult. C
Medidor actual anterior
BD6687 40994 40539 1 ¿
Apoyo gubernamental")

library(dplyr)
text2 <- strsplit(text, "\n") %>% unlist()
addressline <- which(grepl("address", text2, ignore.case = T))
addresslines <- c(addressline+1:2)
address_extracted <- text2[addresslines]
address_extracted
[1] "GALEANA CENTRO LERDO. C.P." "35150 LERDO, DGO."
```

Comment: I tried that, but I have lots of images and text that I don't need is very close to text that I do need. That's why I just croped the right half and some of the top. Now, from the result (which I think is very good), I want to select the part that I need. The ocr() function returns plain text, so I was hoping to be able to work with that.

Comment: see edits. In general you can use `grep` or `grepl` to locate text inside text