# Image to text conversion python

Tags: python-3.x, ocr, python-tesseract

i am trying to extract only the highlighted text from an image using pytesseract module in python.

Issue is that i am unable to extract the highlighted part and the whole image is getting converted to text, and i have no idea how to extract specific part based on the background colour.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve it is by crop and send just the part you need from the image, it will also improve the performance.

There is a related discussion that may help -> [Select part of text that was extracted using the Tesseract OCR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53185255/select-part-of-text-that-was-extracted-using-the-tesseract-ocr)